# when csv file column value contains field terminator value then how to avoid the exception in bulk insert SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

[image]I have a csv file with few columns, Address column contain the values like:

"james street, green park hotel road, NewJersy"

this is my bulk insert script; its working fine when address field is not having ",".  due to match with FieldTerminator value in script its treating address field value comma as a field terminator so the remaining part of value is moving to next field.As a customer given csv file we can't do any changes in it.So how to make them work without missing commas in address field

thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Why do *you* assume that the contents are `"james street, green park hotel road, NewJersy"` instead of `"james street,` ? Only because you assume that there is a *text* separator, the `"` character. What if it was `'`? BULK INSERT isn't a CSV import tool, it's what its name says - a BULK import tools whose job is to load data as fast as possible without parsing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541165/commas-causing-a-problem-using-bulk-insert-and-a-format-file

Comment: I just mentioned the address field value in double quotes here. Actually there is no " double quotes in field value

Comment: Then you don't have an address field at all. You have 3 fields. If you *didn't* use the double quotes, no *human* would be able to guess if this is just one field or many

Comment: The duplicate shows how to use a format file to use a different separator for each column, including text qualifiers. You can't import a single field with commas if there is no way to determine if these are one field or three. Try changing the *export* script to use a text qualifier, or a field separator that isn't likely to appear in text, eg a tab, `|` or `¤`. Tab-separated files are the easiest way to deal with such problems

Comment: Unless it is impossible (I don't see why) I would ask the person that sent this file to send me tab delimited or CSV with quoted values. This doesn't answer the question I know, just a thought if possible to solve without extra coding why not?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

[Error file property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

```
  BULK INSERT dbo.NPI_tbl
    FROM 'd:\npiData\yourfilename.csv'
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    ERRORFILE = 'd:\npiData\ErrorFile.csv',
    TABLOCK
    )
```

oh sorry then use [OPENROWSET](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/bulk-inserts-via-tsql-in-sql-server/) it allow you to select then insert.
so after select you can clean data then insert

```
INSERT INTO 
  dbo.NPI_tbl
SELECT *
FROM 
  OPENROWSET(BULK 'd:\npiData\yourfilename.csv',
  FORMATFILE = 'd:\npiData\npiFormat_c.fmt'
  ) AS e;
```

Comment: This would *discard* rows, not import them

Comment: this one skip the rows which have format problems

Comment: I have added my csv file

Comment: @Kumar..the script getting error "XML parsing: line 1, character 0, one root element".

Comment: how come you finsih so early ? first learn to use openrowset.learn to use formatfile.if fmt not working then use txt file.